# Add a record (that does not already exist) to a table from a userform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add a record to a table based on the value in a textbox on a form IF the value does not already exist in the table. I tried using INSERT INTO unsuccessfully. I've also tried this. I've seen alot out of the internet regarding how to add a record to a table based on a different table, but not based on the value in a userform. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
Update tb1
Set Company = [forms]![form2]![Text0] 
WHERE  ([forms]![form2]![Text0] NOT IN tb1);
```

Comment: You can't update a value that doesn't exist ... Perhaps you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: I rephrased. To "add a record"

Comment: If these are text fields you need to put them inside single quotes like this (if using VBA): DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tb1 Set Company = '" & [forms]![form2]![Text0] &"'" and obviously you need INSERT to add a new record, not UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be like:

```
Insert Into Tb1 ( Company )
Select First(NewCompany)
From Tb1
Where NewCompany Not In (Select Company From Tb1 Where Company = NewCompany)
Having First(NewCompany) Is Not Null;
```

You will have to either pass *NewCompany* as a parameter or replace it with your *Forms* reference.